# How to display Google Locations reviews on my website with google api?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, reactjs, google-my-business-api

I know this question is common, however, I couldn't find any straight answers.
All the answers have mentioned what is required to achieve this but no end solutions at all.
Neither de G Docs are straightful on that.
I´m trying to use the Google My Business API to get the reviews and ratings for a company wtih a group of locations  fully verified by Google. (https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data)
My only one Goal for now is to list all Google Reviews, and display them on the website of the company. Make an API call (properly GET) via Ajax/PHP, or likely.
API response with a list of google reviews (JSON format)
Display the results in HTML.

- I have already followed the Prerequisites instruction step by step:
  Already have approval and test my API Creds with OAuth2 playground, and it's working fine.
  I managed to get the {accoundId} and {locationId} ([https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews/](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/locations/%7BlocationId%7D/reviews/))
  I managed to fetch all the reviews by adding access token - ([https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews/?access_token=token](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/locations/%7BlocationId%7D/reviews/?access_token=token)), But that's all been done through the OAuth2playground - The issue is I want to display the reviews on the website not by Google OAuth playground as it will get expired and reviews will not be updated automatically on the website.

I couldn't find any PHP / Javascript Code examples to start implementing this on company´s website. I was slightly confused about how to use the Google PHP Client Library for that. Too many ways, but none worked at my tests (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

If so, would this approach, will always prompt to ask the user to select which account to log in to? which is not the behavior I am looking for. I only want to get all the reviews and display them on the website, which should not require any login for the user.

It would be helpful if you could share the code and procedure.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Best regards

Comment: Its the same as me, went through Google PHP Client Libraries and all my tests did not work.

Comment: For sure Bro! The Google Team are changing lot of its politics and there´s many API that are deprecated. I´m wating for this changes to become stable to implement my code.
The Google account that my customer use on GCP Console is the basic one, and the support is so poor that the were limited to say to me that they´re ain´t has a solution to my needs... So, just wait and see...

Answer (score 4):

Google lets you pull 5, it's been this way for a long, long time.

I wrote an API that interfaces with Google to do what you need, all you need is the Place ID and you can get the historic reviews, once you obtain historic reviews you can use the native API for real-time, don't hammer the API else it'll cap you :)

Hope it helps, see demo URL below (just swap the place ID with the ones you need and save what you consume to reviews.json and you have historic ratings).

https://api.reviewsmaker.com/gmb/?placeid=ChIJCezbnsal2YgRySx0GXk5hEo

[image: Google Reviews API]

Comment: Hi @ilanP, thanks for your time. It´s like helpful for now. I´ve tested your API on postman and it works fine. I´ve totally apprecciate that man, But if I may, I´m wandering that, in my client case, here´s the situation. He own a website, basic one, and also owns 3 verified locations on GMB, and he ask to me to write a section on his site, like a "testimonials". with this list of reviews, of the 3 locations/places, you got it? For now i´ll try to use your api to build this widget, tests only, if you give your permission, meanwhile i´ll keep tracking another solutions. ok?
Thanks again!

Comment: Sure - I would harvest all his location's historical data, once you got them all save them so you don't have to consume the API again; you can use Google's places API (native API) to continue fetching the latest 5 reviews and move forward from there - That would be my suggestion; I am happy I could provide some help.

Comment: Thanks Dude! it help me a lot. What code basis did you did your code? I mean, your API, is C#, DotNet, PHP, Java, Js? Ihad enormous difficulty to follow the leading of the G Support and Docs and they didn´t gave the attention i needed. Just a short email saying that they couldn´t help. Maybe cos i´m a Free user/Developer and the accounts that i´m managing in Business Profile Adm isn´t paid yet, too. But that´s it, it´s real life, isn´t it?
Well, thank you again for your support and time, i´m really apprecciate that.
Best Regards and have a nice weekend, Dude! ;)

Comment: Thank @IlanP, this saved be a bunch of time.

Comment: Thank you very much Ilan P. I have tried Google's tools many times, but the result is unusable. Why Google can't clean up the job so much is a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Typically using an API involves,

1. Fetching data from a URL
2. Looping through/Using the data to do (output?) something

#### Example PHP implementation

Here's a PHP example implementation from one of my old projects. https://gist.github.com/shramee/fc115a909fd1f8726a589d1b0b351e3e

##### Fetching the reviews

We use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) to fetch the reviews.

```
/**
 * Get google reviews
 * @return array Google reviews data
 */
function get_google_reviews(){

    // URL to fetch
    $google_api = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=<your_place_id>&sensor=true&key=<key>';

    // Fetch reviews with cURL
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $google_api);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // JSON decode the text to associative array
    return json_decode($response, 'assoc');
}
```

##### Looping though the reviews

We then loop through the reviews and output some HTML,

```
// See if we got some reviews
if ($g_response && $g_response['result'] && $g_response['result']['reviews']) {
    // Loop through the reviews
    foreach ($g_response['result']['reviews'] as $review) {
        // Output HTML for reviews
        ?>
        <dl>
            <dt> date </dt>
            <dd><?php echo $review['time'] ?></dd>
            <dt> rating </dt>
            <dd><?php echo $review['rating'] ?></dd>
            <dt> name </dt>
            <dd><?php echo $review['author_name'] ?></dd>
            <dt> content </dt>
            <dd><?php echo $review['text'] ?></dd>
        </dl>
        <?php
    }
}
```

---

For JavaScript, you'd use something like [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)/[axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to get the data and then loop through the items to create some React elements or do some DOM manipulation.

Comment: How about using Google My Business API  to get business reviews instead of Google Place API?

Comment: @Kaloy You can swap out `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api...` with My Business API URL and look at what you get.

Comment: I´ll try your code to see if it works for the project that i´m involved. and after i´ll bring the results here! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it isn't too late for the answer.

One approach is to store the clientId, clientSecret, and refreshToken generated from the Auth2.0 playground on your server. Periodically refresh the accessToken (POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token) when it expires.

Afaik, Google doesn't permit the use of service accounts for GMB, so this seems to be the only way.

P.S. You'll need to address scenarios where your Auth creds become invalid. (Should not happen ideally)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35443199)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).